# Is there a tpl.php file generated by Drupal 7 for custom content types

Tags: 7, theming

I seem to remember it being mentioned somewhere in the past that when you create a new content type in Drupal 7 that there is a corresponding node--[content-type].tpl.php file created somewhere by Drupal core. I may be wrong. However, if there is such a file created, how do I find it so I can copy it in to my theme?

Maybe it defaults to the node.tpl.php file, but I thought a new file for the custom content was created. Just don't know where to find it if it is created.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; Drupal doesn't ever create template files dynamically.

For new content types the default node.tpl.php, or the one provided by the enabled theme, will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can per content type. Use #2 under node at https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656#node-suggestion it should be node--[type].tpl.php.

So for lets say a content type that has the machine name blog, it would be node--blog.tpl.php

As Clive said Drupal doesn't do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks - I thought there was one generated automatically. No idea where that thought came from - perhaps template files in relation to contrib modules...

I just decided to use the base node.tpl.php file and add in my custom field for the content type.